# Using Google Sheets INDIRECT function to find the top and bottom rows

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula

I've been working on a function using `SUM INDIRECT` in Google Sheets, as I want the `SUM` to include newly added rows.

The function I have so far is:

`=SUM(INDIRECT("F5:F"&ROW()-1))`

I have this function in multiple places throughout my spreadsheet, always tracking the F column. I basically separated my sheet into sections.

My issue is that I need to be able to add or remove rows from anywhere in the sheet, but if I do that if throws off the range specified in my formulas.

What I'd like to do is keep the same functionality, but find a way to tell the function where to start that isn't just giving it a row number.

Any ideas on how I can go about this?

Comment: have you some other fixed value in your ranges that you can reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(F5); COLUMN(F5))&":"&
              ADDRESS(ROW()-1; COLUMN(F5))))
```

this way reference is free so by adding/removing columns/rows it will dynamic

if column is always F you can do:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(F5); 6)&":"&
              ADDRESS(ROW()-1; 6)))
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I've never used the address function before but this seems to have worked putting it into my sheet this morning. Time to do a bit of research on this I think.